# How to force unique usernames in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to find if a username already exists in my MongoDB, and if it does, add a random number to it, and then check again with the random number added, and keep checking until no match is found.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
function changeName(x, callback){
    MongoClient.connect(URI, function(err, db){
        db.collection('users').findOne({"user": x}, function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            if (result !== null){
                console.log("match found, changing name...");
                if(result.user){console.log("result.user = " + result.user)}
                //change name.
                x = x + Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
                changeName(x,function(){console.log("callback")});
            }
            console.log("x = " + x);
            console.log("no match!");
            name = x;
        });
    });
    callback();
}
```

And then, once the name has been changed to a unique name, I want to create a new document in the db. Here is the function being called with the db insert as the call back function:

```
changeName(name, function(){    
    db.collection('users').insertOne({
        "user" : name, "email": account.email, "createdAt":new Date()
    });
});
```

The problem is that the original name is what is being sent to the db. I thought using a callback is what I need here, but perhaps I am not using it correctly. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write it as a comment because this might not be the working answer but the text was too long

```
var cb;
    function changeName(x, callback){
        if(callback) {cb = callback;} //dirty hack
        MongoClient.connect(URI, function(err, db){
            db.collection('users').findOne({"user": x}, function(err, result){
                if (err) throw err;
                if (result !== null){
                    console.log("match found, changing name...");
                    if(result.user){console.log("result.user = " + result.user)}
                    //change name.
                    x = x + Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
                    changeName(x);
                    //the function(){console.log} was overriding callback
                }
                console.log("x = " + x);
                console.log("no match!");
                name = x;
            });
        });
        cb(); //the cached function gets called
    }
```